# Azure Service Bus Upcoming Changes

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I got a mail from Microsoft yesterday about upcoming changes in the Azure Services. There, I found a [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/service-bus-name-change/) saying that the units of Standard Azure Service Bus is going to be modified.

Is this going to affect my billing? I don't understand what `direct unit of measure` and `EA unit of measure` mean. Any insight on this will be helpful.

Screenshot of the mail,

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you copy the contents of that email here in the question.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have added the screenshot of the mail to the question

Comment: Billing names will change, that's it.

Comment: Thanks @SeanFeldman :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, it will not affect your billing. Just the unit of measure names of billing will change, the `EA` in `EA unit of measure` means the customers with an Enterprise Agreement (EA customers).

For more details about azure bill, see [Understand your bill for Microsoft Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-understand-your-bill).